# echo PHP variable messages to php form

Tags: php, forms, validation, echo

I have a basic post form in new.php and I am wondering how I can echo (or display) php script variable messages from new1.php on it.

new.php:

```
 <body>
<div id="contact_form">
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="new1.php" id="contact">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="firstName" id="firstName_label">First Name*:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="36" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="firstName" id="firstName_error">This field is required.</label>
      <br />
            <label for="lastName" id="lastName_label">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="36" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="lastName" id="lastName_error">This field is required.</label>
      <br />
      <label for="email" id="email_label">Email*:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>
      <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error2">This is not a valid email address.</label>
      <br />
      <label for="postcode" id="postcode_label">Postcode:</label>
      <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" size="12" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="postcode" id="postcode_error">This field is required.</label>

        <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

new1.php - returns the messages in $msg_to_user. As you can see I echo them on this page, but how can I echo them back to new.php where the form is?

```
<?php
// set variables to null
$firstName   = "";
$lastName    = "";
$email       = "";
$postcode    = "";
$msg_to_user = "";


include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

// set variables from form
// be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection, filter before querying database
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName  = $_POST['lastName'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$postcode  = $_POST['postcode'];

$sql     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

// first name is mandatory
if (!$firstName) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Please enter your name.</font></h4>';

    // email is mandatory
} else if (!$email) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Please type an email address ' . $firstName . '.</font></h4>';

    // check email is valid
} else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is not a valid email address.               </font></h4>';

    // check postcode is a number
} else if (!is_numeric($postcode)) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be a numeric value.</font></h4>';

    // check postcode is greater than 4 chars
} else if (strlen ($postcode) < 4) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be at least 4 characters.</font></h4>';

    // check postcode is less than 12 chars
} else if (strlen ($postcode) > 12) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Postcode must be less than 12 characters.</font></h4>';

    // check email doesn't exist    
} else if ($numRows > 0) {
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in the system.</font></h4>';

    // if all test passed, insert details into database
} else {
    $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (firstName, lastName, email, postcode, dateTime) 
                                                    VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$postcode',now() )") or die(mysql_error());

    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="0066FF">Thanks ' . $firstName . $lastName . ' , you have been added successfully.</font></h4>';




    $firstName = "";
    $lastName  = "";
    $email     = "";
    $postcode  = "";
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<p>First Name: <?php
echo $firstName;
?></p>
<p>Last Name: <?php
echo $lastName;
?></p>
<p>Email: <?php
echo $email;
?></p>
<p>Postcode: <?php
echo $postcode;
?></p>
<p>Message: <?php
echo $msg_to_user;
?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no sense. plz make clear the question.

Comment: take message in session. and then print it on new.php

Comment: are you trying to go to new.php -> new1.php -> new.php again?

Comment: after posting the form data to new1.php, if any messages are encountered and the $msg_to_user is not null. I want to display these messages back to new.php where the web form is

Comment: send one variable through url using header and verify that variable in  first page and echo appropriate message

Comment: @DLO How would you like your script to return back to the `new.php`? I doesnt seen any redirect in `new1.php`

Comment: may be....you can use action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" on new.php & put your new1.php code to the new.php....

Comment: @DLO I think Dev is right instead of creating an new file for displaying it. set action as itself.

Comment: I agree with them. Something like a postback effect.:)

Comment: @ Dev and @ Kaii. You are correct, it doesn't make sense to have it in separate php files. I was going to use ajax, but I want to keep the non 'javascript' users in mind. In the end it was kinda a stupid question, but I am now aware of php sessions :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ajax` or `php sessions` to do do this.

This is how to do it using `php sessions`.

**In new1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$variable;
```

**In new.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is, redirect to new.php from new1.php using header function. While redirecting, pass the $msg_to_user through the url.

To do that add the following code in your new1.php right after assigning proper value to $msg_to_user

```
header("location: new.php?msg_to_user=".$msg_to_user);
exit;
```

and in new.php add the following code:

```
echo $_GET['msg_to_user']; //this will display the message
```

Another way to do this is using session to access the value across the pages.

In new1.php insert the following code to set the message in a session variable:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['msg_to_user'] = $msg_to_user;
header("location: new.php);
exit;
```

And in new.php add the following code to retrieve the message that is set in new1.php:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['msg_to_user'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg_to_user'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg_to_user']);//After displaying the message unset it, to make sure that the message is displayed only once.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass validation message with session. 
And than remove session value with `$_SESSION['name']='';`
so message display only one time.